# Creating a priority search tree to find number of points in the range [-inf, qx] X [qy, qy'] from a set of points sorted on y-coordinates in O(n) time

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry

A priority search tree can be constructed on a set of points P in O(n log(n)) time but if the points are sorted on the y co-ordinates then it takes O(n) time. I find algorithms for constructing the tree when the points are not sorted.

I am thinking of a way to do this, which is as follows:

1. Construct a BST on the points.
    Since the points are sorted then it will take O(n) time.

   I followed the approach given in this [link](https://www.rhyscitlema.com/algorithms/sorted-list-to-complete-bst/) for this step.
2. Check if all the nodes satisfy the min-heap property based on the x-coordinates

   This will take O(n) time.

So total time complexity will be O(n)

Is this a valid approach to construct a Priority Search Tree in O(n) time, from a set of points sorted on the y-coordinates??

Comment: What did you try first in order to mathematically prove that your approach works?

Comment: @jbapple I mentioned in the questioned whatever I tried. And I don't know if my approach is actually a valid approach and hence the question. I have asked if the 2 steps I have mentioned in the question will give me the result I want to prove.

Comment: An attempt at a mathematical proof usually doesn't stop as early as yours did. It often involves making suppositions, attempting induction proofs, testing medium cases and devising lemmata. If you're not comfortable with these yet, that's OK! But the best way to learn how to analyze data structures will definitely involve understanding how to read and write proofs, so I'd suggest going back to your algorithms textbook and doing some end-of-chapter exercises.

Comment: @jbapple I found this link (https://www.rhyscitlema.com/algorithms/sorted-list-to-complete-bst/) which describes the way I am building the BST. and since Heap is a complete binary tree, the next step I am doing is to check all elements if they satisfy the heap property, based on the x coordinate values. Both this takes O(n) time and hence I inferred that the whole process will take O(n) time.

Comment: `2.` would yield satisfies by mere lucky coincidence, only - what if not?

Comment: Exercise 10.2 from *Mark de Berg, Otfried Cheong, Marc van Kreveld, Mark Overmars: Computational geometry* seems to make the $O(n)$ claim quoted.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, I have seen this question in that book and in assignments of several renowned institutes and also got this question as an assignment in my own institute. I don't know much myself but if it is not possible to get O(n) time complexity, would it be given at so many places?

Comment: Currently I think you have been right on track until you dropped `Min-Heapify` for `Check`. The catch may be in `on the x-coordinates` (or the level of abstraction in the description): in every node, there is a $y$-coordinate telling *lesser* from *no less* and an $x$-coordinate for *top priority*. I don't see how to do without either another $y$- or another $x$-value. You got to be careful to *not* change the BST in *Min-Heapify*.

Comment: `I have seen this question in that book` by all means, make it a habit to properly attribute content you didn't originate. And to not change around a question while a bounty is pending, clarifications excepted.

Comment: @greybeard From Mark de Berg, Otfried Cheong, Marc van Kreveld, Mark Overmars: Computational geometry...`It’s straightforward to derive a recursive O(nlogn) algorithm for building a
priority search tree. Interestingly, priority search trees can even be built in linear
time, if the points are already sorted on y-coordinate. The idea is to construct
the tree bottom-up instead of top-down, in the same way heaps are normally
constructed.` Page No. 228. (At the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make PST in O(N)

The simple is answer is *No*. It will take a minimum $O(NlogN)$ time to construct the tree.

> Is this a valid approach to construct a Priority Search Tree in O(n) time, from a set of points sorted on the y-coordinates.

*No*, the algorithm you mentioned will fail when you try to maintain the min-heap property based on $x-coordinates$.When you perform the *min-heapify* operation, the $y-coordinates$ will move from original position and the property of BST (based on $y-coordinates$) will fail. You can't maintain BST property for $y-coordinates$ anymore. So the tree will just reduce to min-heap  based on $x-coordinates$.

Here's a thought to construct priority search tree sorted on $Y$-coordinates:

For a given set of points $S$(sorted on $X$-coordinates), create a priority search tree as follows:

1. If $S$ is empty, return a NULL pointer and stop.
2. The point $P$ in $S$ with the greatest $Y$-coordinate becomes the root $R$.
3. If  $S-P$ is an empty set , then $R$ is a leaf so we return it and stop.
4. Let $X(P)$ be a value such that half of points in $S-P$ have
   $X$-coordinate lower than $X(P)$, and half having higher value. Basically $X(P)$ is median(based on $X$) of your $S-P$
5. Recursively create a priority search tree on the lower half of $S-P$,
   let its root be the left child of $R$.
6. Recursively create a priority search tree on the upper half of $S-P$,
   let its root be the right child of $R$.

Total time complexity will be $O(nlogn)$ as the tree will be height balanced.

Notes:

1. Since you have sorted points based on $X$coordinates finding median will take $O(1)$.
2. To find the maximum $Y$, for simplification you could also maintain a max-heap based on $Y$. Finding maximum $Y$ from it and subsequently removing from it during creation of priority search tree will take $O(logn)$.

Comment: And what if we start building the BST by taking the middle element as root, then the middle of the left half as the root of the left subtree and the middle element of the right half as the root of the right subtree. Shouldn't the BST constructed in this way be balanced and take O(n) time?

Comment: No you are getting it wrong. Think of it as inserting $N$ elements where insertion of each element takes $O(h)$ where $h=log(N)$ if the tree is balanced. So time complexity for creating the tree is $O(NlogN)$

Comment: Have a look at this link 
https://www.rhyscitlema.com/algorithms/sorted-list-to-complete-bst/

Comment: You should note it says *Sorted List*, which you don't have. If you have points sorted before hand then you could construct the balanced BST in $O(N)$ time. But unless you have the points sorted it will take $O(NlogN)$ no matter how you construct it.

Comment: I mentioned that in my question. I hope you noticed that.

Comment: I think I messed up BST and PST. Take a look at the updated answer. I think it will solve your queries.

Comment: My main objective is to construct a min-heap based on x-coordinates, then why should I even care about the property of BST being maintained or not?

Comment: Be clear about it. You should mention that you just need min-heap based on x-coodinates. You have mentioned in the question you want to make *Priority search tree* which adds *BST* property over *Heap* to make efficient searching. So you need to care about BST property being maintained.

Comment: Yes, I have studied this http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs252/misc/resources/lectures/pdf/notes07.pdf and your answer does not satisfy my question. Your solution still gives O(N logN) whereas I have clearly mentioned in my question that I am trying to find an algorithm which takes O(N) time.

Comment: Read the updated answer. In short there's no way to make the PST in $O(N)$ time. The detailed explanation is in answer itself.

Comment: `[for] maximum Y, […] maintain a max-heap based on Y` how do you handle this in recursion?

Comment: @Siladittya: `[this] answer does not satisfy my question` as of Sep 20, your question reads as quoted by tanmay_freak: `Is this a valid approach to construct a Priority Search Tree in O(n) time, from a set of points sorted on the y-coordinates?`

Comment: @greybeard The answer was a lot different when I wrote that. The answer was updated after that.

Comment: @tanmay_freak `It’s straightforward to derive a recursive O(nlogn) algorithm for building a
priority search tree. Interestingly, priority search trees can even be built in linear
time, if the points are already sorted on y-coordinate. The idea is to construct
the tree bottom-up instead of top-down, in the same way heaps are normally
constructed.` From Mark de Berg, Otfried Cheong, Marc van Kreveld, Mark Overmars: Computational geometry Page No. 228 (At the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a valid approach to construct a Priority Search Tree in O(n) time, from a set of points sorted on the y-coordinates?

*No*.
In [revision 8](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/114939/8), it constructs a valid search tree on $y$.
The check in step 2 will almost always yield ***not*** satisfied.

The best I thought up, ignoring non-unique priority values:

Proceed the complete binary search tree construction as usual, annotating each node with a priority value that allows to bound searches in the sub-tree it roots.
Inserting node $k$, the path to/from the root will have a length equal the the depth of $k$, and for "the priority side of a PST under construction", its value would have to be annotated to an unknown number of nodes, worst case: to every one on this path for a total of $O(n \log n)$ construction time.
If instead of annotating this "winner", D.E. Knuth presents annotating the loser in TAoCP 5.4.1:
*this is the top priority in this sub-tree without the values on the path from the root*.
Here, only *one* node needs to be annotated, it is on the path between the node inserted in the previous step and the root, with priority increasing in this direction: one can find it in $O(\log \log n)$ steps for a total of $O(n \log \log n)$ construction time.

This does *not* yield a PST.
It *should* yield a search tree supporting $[-inf, qx] \times [qy, qy']$ queries no worse than a PST does.