# finding an algorithm for creating a priority search tree in linear time with presorting

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, trees, binary-trees, binary-search-trees

> A priority search tree is a binary tree satisfying the following:

- every node $u$ stores a point $p_u = (x_u,y_u)$
- every nonleaf $u$ stores an x-coordinate $x_u'$ called the split-line coordinate.
- If $v$ is a descendant of $u, y_v\leq y_u$.
- If $v$ is in the left subtree of $u$, then $x_v < x_u$ and if $v$ is in the right subtree of $u$, then $x_v \ge x_u$.

Source: the above definition is a variant of the one used in this question: [Creating a priority search tree to find number of points in the range [-inf, qx] X [qy, qy'] from a set of points sorted on y-coordinates in O(n) time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/114939/creating-a-priority-search-tree-to-find-number-of-points-in-the-range-inf-qx)

> I was wondering how, if given a set of $n$ points in general position sorted by $x$-coordinate, one could construct a priority search tree in worst case linear time?

I know how to create a priority search tree in $O(n\log n)$ worst case time. I thought of creating a BST of x-coordinates and then doing an in-place fix with rotations to ensure the heap property is maintained. For each node $u,$ we can then let $x_u'=x_u$, the x-coordinate of the point it stores. However, this algorithm doesn't seem to run in linear time (since while doing the in-place fix the number of rotations could be close to linear for many points).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is essentially a [Cartesian tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tree):

> The Cartesian tree for a sequence of distinct numbers can be uniquely
> defined by the following properties:
>
> 1. The Cartesian tree for a sequence has one node for each number in the sequence. Each node is associated with a single sequence value.
> 2. A symmetric (in-order) traversal of the tree results in the original sequence. That is, the left subtree consists of the values
>    earlier than the root in the sequence order, while the right subtree
>    consists of the values later than the root, and a similar ordering
>    constraint holds at each lower node of the tree.
> 3. The tree has the heap property: the parent of any non-root node has a smaller value than the node itself.

Just transform the $n$ points $p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_n$ where $x_0\le x_1\le \cdots \le x_n$ into an array $A$ where $A[i]=-y_i$, and construct the Cartesian tree for this array. The Cartesian tree meets all your requirements.

There are several methods to construct a Cartesian tree in linear time. I quote a simple one from Wikipedia here:

> One method is to simply process the sequence values in left-to-right
> order, maintaining the Cartesian tree of the nodes processed so far,
> in a structure that allows both upwards and downwards traversal of the
> tree. To process each new value x, start at the node representing the
> value prior to x in the sequence and follow the path from this node to
> the root of the tree until finding a value y smaller than x. The node
> x becomes the right child of y, and the previous right child of y
> becomes the new left child of x. The total time for this procedure is
> linear, because the time spent searching for the parent y of each new
> node x can be charged against the number of nodes that are removed
> from the rightmost path in the tree.